# Can I play Vindictus on Mac?

Tags: macos, virtualization, vindictus

I am playing Vindictus and I would like to know if this game will appear on Mac OS.

Other than that, do you know a way to play on mac (virtualbox or others)?

Comment: I wouldn't try playing any games (other than maybe chess or solitaire) through VirtualBox.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have a more resent Mac with an Intel processor you can use [Boot Camp](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/) with a full version of Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with a recent Mac you can play it, either natively using Boot Camp or in a Virtual Machine.  The performance you get will depend greatly on your system (i.e. discrete graphics, i7>Core2Duo).

On an early 2011 Macbook Pro with Sandy Bridge i7 and an AMD Radeon HD 6750M Graphics card, it plays maxed out fast as anything in a Virtual Machine.  VMware Fusion and Parallels Desktop for Mac typically have much better performance, but are not free like VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

Your choices at this point are either the virtualization of Windows (VM Ware, Parallels, etc) or you can dual boot via [Boot Camp](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/) into Windows. Since Boot Camp comes with every Intel based Mac all you need is a copy of Windows to boot into. I recommend keeping Windows on an external hard drive.

Answer (score -1):

no, there is no way to play on mac ;)

Comment: On native OSX no... but VirtualBox is mentioned so clearly using Boot Camp to install a full version of Windows isn't out of the question.